# cakephp website confusing load times

Tags: performance, cakephp, plugins, load

I have a website that uses CakePHP 1.3.10. This CakePHP app it's pretty big, not in the amount of models or controllers (like 5 of each), but in the amount of plugins. I use the plugins as places of the website where users can access (or can't access) depending on if they have logged in already or not (well there's more reasons, but it's not important now, it's how it works). I also use a global Auth component in the app_controller.php

My issue is the following: I've noticed that the website is getting really slow when trying to access any of the pages of a plugin (when accessing the "home" page - which is not in a plugin - all is good).

The thing is that I was going to run some performance tests to figure out what's going on. I decided to create another website, exactly like the one I described, with the only difference that I removed all the plugins with the exception of one.

Amazingly (for me), when I access one of the pages of this plugin that I didn't delete, it goes super fast, like it should normally go.

So my question is: does the number of plugins really have a direct impact on the loading times of a page inside those plugins? Is there any way to "fix" this? Or is it just a coincidence and something else is going on that I missed?

Thanks so much in advance for any advise!

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the amount of files and folders of my application has increased significantly the load times. I don't know what is the relation between amount of files/folders and loading speed in CakePHP, but it's a fact, at least in my website.

I've changed my cake installation to an advanced installation (as it explains in the cakephp boo) to have my files more spread out in different sub-apps, instead of having one huge app, and this has helped a lot!